# defining function using a struct

Tags: c++, function, vector, struct

I'm a newbie to programming, especially to C++. I've got a task, and its part is to write a function using a struct.

```
struct S {
    float m; //how many
    int h; //where
    float mx;
};

int main() {
    S s;
    s.m=0.5;
    s.h=1;

    vector<float> v(10);
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
        v[i]=sin(i);
    S mx = max_search(v);
```

The function is ok, if (`mx.m>0.98935 && mx.m<0.9894 && mx.h==8`).

I came out with this code of function, but I know, it's quite defective.

```
float max_search(vector<float> v) {
    int max=0;
    for (int i=0; i<v.size(); i++) {
       if (v[i]>max) {
        max=v[i];
       }
    return max;
    }
}
```

I don't know, what should I do with the type of function, and maybe the return value in also wrong.

Comment: You are returning within your for loop. Soit will execute only once.

Comment: Since you don't need to copy the vector, pass it by `const` reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I capture your main question correctly or not. You want to convert return value of max_search function which is `float to struct S`? I'll massage on KarithikT's answer and add more details:

To enable `implicit conversion` (from float to struct S), need to add conversion functions to `S`

```
struct S {
  S():m(0.0), h(0), mx(0.0){ }         //
  S(float x):m(0.0), h(0), mx(x){  }   // to enalbe convert float to S
    float m; //how many
    int h; //where
    float mx;    
};

float max_search(const vector<float>& v) { // pass by const reference
    float max=0.0f;  
    for (int i=0; i<v.size(); i++) {
       if (v[i]>max) {
        max=v[i];
       }
    }
    return max;  
}
```

You could also use std::max_element to find max element from a container:

```
vector<float> v(10);
for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
   v[i]=sin(i);
 }
S mx = *std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

You want your `return max;` In  the outer most level. Right now it returns every iteration of the for loop, which means you get only 1 iteration.

```
float max_search(vector<float> v) {
    float max=0.0f;    <------------
    for (int i=0; i<v.size(); i++) {
       if (v[i]>max) {
        max=v[i];
       }
    -------------- 
    }
    return max;   <------------
}
```

And i think you want to call it like this  `s.mx = max_search(v);`

You can also use [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element)

```
s.mx = std::max_element(v.begin(),v.end()); // (begin(v),end(v)) in c++11
```

Comment: Aww, thanks I was inattentive, I corrected mistakes in max_search(). Actually, you're right, but I can't change anything in main(), and that's why `S mx=max_search(v)` must stay. So I keep getting this message: "conversion from 'float' to non-scolar type 'S' requested".

Comment: Of course, because what you really want to do is `s.mx = max_search(v);`

Comment: @user1846813 if the code that you cant change is given by your instructor, you might want to reconfirm if it isnt a typo, because the entire statement just screams typo!

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a function as `float`, why are you returning an `int`?

```
float max_search(vector<float> v) {
  float max = v[0]; //this way you avoid an iteration
  for (int i = 1; i < v.size() - 1; i++)
    if (v[i] > max) max = v[i];
  return max;
}
```

You can also use an iterator to do that:

```
float max_search(vector<float> v) {
  float max = .0;
  for (vector<float>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
    if (*it > max) max = *it;
  return max;
}
```

In the first code block it's important to substract 1 to `v.size`, other way you will try to access to an element that does not exists. If your code isn't returning you a segmentation fault, that's because `std::vector` is access safe. That means that `std::vector` **try** to access to the element, but anyway, you are doing one last innecesary iteration. That's why it's better to use iterators.

It's also true what @KarthikT says: you are trying to return `max` in each iteration, so, after first iteration, function return the value and stop the execution, always retrieving you the first value of the vector (if this value is greater than 0).

I hope this help.

Comment: in your second example you have neither declared (or initialised) `max` nor returned it...

Comment: Edited again. In the first block code I've changed `max=v[1]` for `max=v[0]`.